# Showing which article has the most rows in ArticleViews table

Tags: mysql

Showing which article has the most rows in my ArticleViews table (I have no idea how to go about this)

```
+-------------------------+---------------------+-----------                                                                         
| Title            |||||||||||||       DateOfView          |                                                                         
+-------------------------+---------------------+-----------                                                                         
| World Of Warcraft Guide ||||||| 2014-03-17 14:25:00 |                                                                         
| World Of Warcraft Guide ||||||| 2014-03-07 14:25:00 |                                                                         
| World Of Warcraft Guide ||||||| 2014-02-25 14:25:00 |                                                                         
| Leauge Of Legends Guide |||| 2014-03-17 14:25:00 |                                                                         
| Leauge Of Legends Guide |||| 2014-03-07 14:25:00 |                                                                         
| The HearthStone Guide   ||||||||| 2014-03-17 14:25:00 |                                                                         
| The HearthStone Guide   ||||||||| 2014-03-07 14:25:00 |                                                                         
| The HearthStone Guide   ||||||||| 2014-02-25 14:25:00 |                                                                         
| The HearthStone Guide   ||||||||| 2014-01-01 14:25:00 |                                                                         
| How to be the best      ||||||||||||||||| 2014-03-07 14:25:00 |                                                                         
| How to tank in WoW      ||||||||||||||||| 2014-03-17 14:25:00 |                                                                         
+-------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

this is what my table looks like.

I need to write a query that shows which Article has the most views essentially, and I have no idea what query to use. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query will return the article title that has the most views. The `LIMIT 1` will limit the query to returning only 1 result.

```
SELECT Title, count(*) as count FROM ArticleViews GROUP BY Title ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Very useful extra there :)

Answer (score 1):

Your query could be something like the bellow

```
SELECT Title, count(*) as count FROM ArticleViews GROUP BY Title ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Notice the `ORDER BY count DESC` this will order by highest views you can reverse it by doing `ORDER BY count ASC`

You might want to refrain from using capitals in your column name, but I guess that is personal preference.

Summary of **Count**

SQL COUNT function is the simplest function and very useful in counting the number of records, which are expected to be returned by a SELECT statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try this I think it'd help

```
 select count(title) from ArticleViews group by title
```

Comment: This would only give you a count, you would really want to see the title swell so you know what the count value is for.

Comment: yes but I don't think that will be considered enough reason for voting down I just put the answer in rush and with a small modification it'll work  select count(title),title from ArticleViews group by title